# Toggle function problem, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a comment system that posts comments in an ordered list. My requirememnts were to add hide/show toggle function to each comment.

Currently, the toggle function only works on the first comment (even when you try to click on 2nd, 3rd, etc.)

I've tried to use `querySelectAll`, but it didn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<div class="textbox">
  <h3>Leave comments</h3>
  <label for=msg>Name</label><br>
  <input type=text id=fname> <br>
  <label for=msg>Content</label><br>
  <textarea id=msg> </textarea>
  <br>
  <input type=button onclick="postcomments()" value="Send" />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  <ol id="showcomments" style="max-width:200px; font-size:12px; padding-left:10px;">
  </ol>
</div>

<script>
  var ans = [];

  function postcomments() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;

    var lastpos = ans.length;
    var current = new Date();

    console.log(current);

    var time = current.getHours() + ":" + (current.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + current.getMinutes();
    var date = current.getDate() + "." + (current.getMonth() + 1) + "." + current.getFullYear();

    var i = 0;

    ans[lastpos] = '<img src="Media/minusicon.png" alt="minusicon" onclick="toggle(document.getElementById(&quot;txt&quot))" style="width:8%;" id="plusminusicon">' + " " + "Sent By" + " " + '<a href="#.html">' + fname + '</a>' + " " + " In" + " " + date + " " + "At" + " " + time + '<br>' + '<span id="txt" class="toggle_panel">' + msg + '</span>' + '<br>' + '-------------------------------';

    var ol = document.getElementById("showcomments");

    ol.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
      ol.innerHTML += "<li id=" + (i + 1) + ">" + ans[i] + "</li>";
    }
  }

  function toggle(x) {
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";

      document.getElementById("plusminusicon").src = "Media/minusicon.png";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";

      document.getElementById("plusminusicon").src = "Media/plusicon.png";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have always the same id for all "txt" span, so the browser change always the first.
If you don't want change much of your code the simpliest solution is add the lastpost variable to the span id and to the parameter of toggle function.
Here the changes to do:

```
    ans[lastpos] = '<img src="Media/minusicon.png" alt="minusicon" onclick="toggle(' + lastpos + ')" style="width:8%;" id="plusminusicon' + lastpos + '">' + " " + "Sent By" + " " + '<a href="#.html">' + fname + '</a>' + " " + " In" + " " + date + " " + "At" + " " + time + '<br>' + '<span id="txt' + lastpos + '" class="toggle_panel">' + msg + '</span>' + '<br>' + '-------------------------------';

    function toggle(x) {
  let comment = document.getElementById("txt" + x);
  let icon = document.getElementById("plusminusicon" + x);

  if (comment.style.display === "none") {
    comment.style.display = "block";
    icon.src = "Media/minusicon.png";
  } else {
    comment.style.display = "none";
    icon.src = "Media/plusicon.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing! it did solved the comment Hide\Show Issue. However, only the first (the top one) +\- icon changes. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You have the same issue of comment, the same Id for every post icon. I have updated the code. Now it works fine. You have to change the string and the toggle function too.

Answer (score 0):

To bind click listeners to dynamically added elements, you can use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('comment')) {
        // do something
    }
})
```

jQuery makes it even easier.

```
$(document).on('click','.comment',function(){ //do something })
```

And here's a jsfiddle link to the complete code example. https://jsfiddle.net/ep2bnu0g/